# multiple resources to same sprint in TFS2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

i want to assign multiple resources (engineers) to the same sprint. But, not able to find out how to do that.

I want to have two fields "Handler" and "reviewer".  Both are names of engineers (system.AssignedTo) , but this is not allowed in TFS.

Any workaround ?

Comment: I'm curious. From a process point of view, why do you assign resources to a sprint, instead of assigning work items within the sprint to resources?

Comment: Yeah, because there is a main handler to the sprint, who does the technical design, and divides work within the members. So the final responsibility of the the sprint success goes to that resource. There is also a reviewer to the sprint, (usually external) who does does the full review.

Comment: Or in that case, even work items in the sprint also needs a reviewer assigned, so that the handler of the sbi, can reserve the reviewers time for review , or knows whom to contact when he has some queiries over his task.

Comment: So I don't understand why you don't just assign the resources to the work items. Add the main handler to the Sprint work item. Add the reviewer (or reviewers) to the Task work item, etc.

Comment: Yes, but then i have to go through the tasks and see where is the review task and who is it assigned to.  But i want the overview in sprint. Because my handles multiple projects at a time, hence there are multiple sprints (in different) projects going on at a time. So getting an overview from active sprints, i want to make out who are involved in the sprint, also for planning and sending a status to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was so simple..i couldnt believe it. 
Create a new field with a different reference name. Add the rule : AllowValidUser. That will solve the problem :)